# Postgresql regex match all digits in column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, regex

How do I extract all digits from a string with regex in pgsql?

```
select regexp_matches('dsa8a552a5a2a5?', '\d+');
```

Will output only 8.

Need to get `8552525`

Comment: You're actually right. I'll change it to better comply with the rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use `regexp_replace`, globally replacing non-digits by an empty string:

```
select regexp_replace('dsa8a552a5a2a5?', '\D', '', 'g');

 regexp_replace 
----------------
 8552525
```

Comment: I like the posix variant of the same thing:  regexp_replace('dsa8a552a5a2a5?', '[^[:digit:]]','','g')